# JPA virtual partitioning in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, partitioning

My current organization uses Oracle and we need to store large number of rows in a single logical table.

This is a fit case for using partitioning but our Oracle license does not allow use of the native partitioning feature.

I can get an Oracle 12c or 19c instance but neither would have partitioning support.

People in my company have been using multiple tables with year-month suffix like `data_2021_01`, `data_2021_02`, `data_2021_03` to limit data in a single table needs to hold. But having multiple tables creates hurdles when using JPA which expects single table per entity.

**Is there some way I can make JPA work with single Java entity backed by multiple tables based on certain value (like CREATE_DATE) present in the entity.**

I am open to using anything either on DB side (other than upgrading the license) or JPA side that will allow me to avoid cramming all rows into a single table. Preferably I do not want to use stored procedures or triggers.

I can accept certain constraints. Like if the (virtual) partitioning is based on `date` then the `date` should always be available when doing create/read/update/delete operations.

I know the proper solution here is to use native partitioning, but sometimes you have to make do with what is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can think of creating a query which represents the union of the data_xx tables, it will be dynamically created, since every month there going to be another table.

Map this query to the `Entity`.

Some solutions are listed here https://tech.asimio.net/2021/07/26/Writing-dynamic-SQL-queries-using-Spring-Data-JPA-Repositories-and-EntityManager.html

PS Please, correct me someone if I can't add external links here

Comment: That only works for reads for writes, you need a table name. Also in case of reads, the view may be slow as it is UNIONing all large tables.

Comment: For reads you can use dynamic query, if you know the date(s), for an instance, you can select from the corresponding table(s) only. If you need to search through all tables, it will be slow in any case, especially if you need some aggregation or cross-rows logic.

Comment: Regarding writes - JPA still needs to know which table you want to write it in. Even if we imagine that we could explain JPA how to combine all these tables under 1 entity, then JPA needs to analyze every entity update and decide, based on the date, which table to put it in; and what if date was changed - it means that instead of update, JPA needs to issue 2 queries: remove from 1 table and insert into another. And I am not mentioning here update queries where you are updating the list of the entities. So for updates you need to come up with some custom logic anyway